# Georeferencing a PDF with pixels coordinates not in corners

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I'm trying to georegister an existing PDF using GDAL.

I have two pixel coordinates and their corresponding locations in the source projection.

```
gdal_translate -of pdf -a_srs "+proj=lcc +ellps=WGS84 +lon_0=xxx +lat_0=yyy +lat_1=xxx +lat2=yyy +datum=WGS84" -a_ullr xmin ymin xmax ymax source.pdf dest.pdf
```

This approach works, but it assumes that the these coordinates are in upper left and lower right corners of the source. I'd need a way of giving also the pixel positions of the points given to a_ullr. Is this possible using gdal_translate? Basically all that would be needed is to be able to specify bounds in the resulting pdf that is not the default 0,0 1,1.

Comment: You might look at the -gcp or Ground Control Point option of gdal_translate to specify pixel to lat/long transformation. If you do use this parameter, you may need to run gdalwarp afterwards.